# Онлайн-кинотеатры и антиплагиат

Tags: веб-программирование

Заметил одну особенность:
Если попытаться сделать скриншот экрана, когда браузер находится не в фокусе, то скриншот проигрываемого фильма становится черным квадратом.

Например, Kinopoisk HD.

Как такое достигается?

Разве из какого-то JS'а можно слушать глобальные сочетания клавиш?

Comment: а если в фокусе, то нормально получается?

Comment: я думал, что это давно известно. Очень часто, плееры используют видеоускорение от видеокарты, то некоторые методы взятия скриншота будут давать черный прямоугольник на месте. И это не только браузеры

Comment: @Эникейщик Неа. Т.е сайт как-то понимает за пределами браузера, что делается скриншот.

Comment: @iluxa1810 в винде есть такая штука как контекст устройства - DC. Скрин снимается с "общего" контекста (dc), а по-хорошему нужно опросить каждый dc и с него сохранить изображение (как это сделать - затрудняюсь сказать). Скорее всего так выходит, что при активном окне изображения в контекстах складываются - и выходит верная картинка. А при снятии с неактивного окна - система не может определить что находится в пересекающихся контекстах, и на всякий случай оставляет dc не заполненым. При использовании 3D ускорителя выделяется отдельный dc с особыми атрибутами. Т.е. это глюк самой винды.

Comment: Дело не в сайте, а в методе показа. См. комментари KoVadim. Во многих плеерах тоже вместо изображения будет черный прямоугольник, если делать скриншот средствами виндовс.

Comment: Типичное поведение для DRM-контента. Делайте скриншоты правильными декодировщиками.

Comment: А когда в фокусе, то скриншот нормальный? Или о чём речь? Если вы просто коряво сформулировали вопрос и в фокусе скриншот тоже чёрный, то значит всё-таки «видеоускорение» и «DRM-контент»

Comment: С этим кстати связан один прикол: если взять этот чёрный цвет (обычно это RGB `#100010` / `16,0,16`) и порисовать этим цветом в другом окне (в том же Paint), то на месте этого цвета появится видео (конкретно на кинопоиске проверить не могу, аккаунта не имею)